# Incorrect reflections when enabling Screen Space Reflection

Tags: reflection

When I turn on Screen Space Reflection to create glass, the bull and chair start to look very unnatural. How to fix it?

[image: Screen Space Reflection off]

[image: Screen Space Reflection on]

Comment: You are in material preview mode, BTW. Make sure you switch to render preview mode to see what it will look like in the render. (Hold Z -> Render Preview Mode)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to fix - screen space reflections are not accurate. They are not meant to be correct, they are supposed to be a cheap way to fake real reflections if they do not matter a lot or if you have situations where they might work OK. You should use Cycles to pathtrace real reflections.